# Length of Triangle BCD

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Length of Triangele]

Hey, well I'm doing some higher level revision and I'm stuck...

In the diagram triangle BCD is mathematically similar to triangle ACE.

So what is the length of BD? How do you work it out?

Comment: We now at least that BD is 3 using the ration: $\frac{10}{4}=(7+0.5)/BD$

Comment: CB can be any integer as long as following condition is met: $CB=\frac{BA}{1.5}$

Comment: Do you have any more information about these triangles, for instance the area?

Comment: The length of BCD? BCD is a triangle. Do you not mean either the length of BD or BC - one of the triangle's sides?

Comment: Sorry yeah BD!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot... lol it's not a really good question... I don't even know how to write properly

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the length of DB from $\triangle ACE\sim \triangle BCD$, the coefficient of similarity is evident from the side $CE$. On the other hand, you can't recover the length $BC$ unless you have any additional information. You may draw several triangles satisfying those lengths but with different $\angle CEA$ (and therefore, different lengths of $AC$).

Answer (score 1):

$$4:DB=10:7\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow DB=\frac{7\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4}{10}=3$$

Comment: It appears that we have different values for DB. Either 5cm or 3cm. However, as I mentioned in my comment above, 3cm is answer obtained using basic knowledge of similar triangles.

Comment: Adi it's homework you dont suppose to give the complete answer just like that!

Answer (score 0):

The ratio DB/EA must equal the ratio DC/EC. Take it from there.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the length of $BCD$. I assume you just mean the length of $BD$?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem tells you that the two triangles are **similar triangles**. Similar triangles **always** have the same three angles (even if they are rotated).

When we have two sides, the angle between them determines the length of the third side, the side opposite the angle. Because the angles of the two triangles are the same (because they are similar triangles), then the sides must be proportionate to one another.

Because the sides are proportionate to one another, we can work out ratios: let's take one side from triangle A and one side from triangle B, both of which are between the **same two angles** (or opposite the same angle). Given that we then have the ratio, we can work out the length of the side we are trying to find.

So let's take side **DC** $=4$ and **EC** $=(4+6)=10.$ Let's divide the **smaller side** by the **bigger side**: $\frac{DC}{EC} = \frac{4}{10}.$ Let's call $\frac{4}{10}$ the **ratio.**

Let's look at the ratio a bit more:
$\frac{Smaller Side}{Bigger Side}= ratio$
 then $Smaller Side = ratio \cdot BiggerSide$
 and $\frac{SmallerSide}{ratio} = BiggerSide$

Now that we have this, we can use it to work out side **BD**. In this case, **BD** is the smaller side, and **EA** is the bigger side. So we use the ratio and the bigger side to find the smaller side:  $Smaller Side = ratio \cdot BiggerSide$
  i.e. $BD = ratio \cdot EA$
$BD = \frac{4}{10} \cdot 7.5$
$\therefore BD = 3$